# multiple vlookup from adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel sheet like below. It shows different teams playing eachother. For example, Team1 plays Team2 and they will get 18 and 44 points respectively. If I input the Teamname, how would I be able to find how many points that team received? i.e. "Team1" would output 18 and "Team8" would output 22.

I am not sure if `vlookup()` will work for me because the first parameter has to be the first column (which would work for Team1-5 but not Team6-10).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a VLOOKUP for the left data and an OFFSET/INDEX MATCH for the right data. I went with the latter which should work.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G1,A:B,2,FALSE),INDEX(C:D,MATCH(G1,D:D,0),1))
```